# Want to get rid out from skipng

Tags: c

It takes only first and second times card and number but on the third time it does not take input and skipping and direct print the else logic but I want to justify my logic correctly. The output is given below:

```
Input 1st card type and number:  S 5
Input 2nd card type and number:  S 5
Input 3rd card type and number:  No Bonanza
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char t_1,t_2,t_3;
    int num1=0,num2=0,num3=0;
    printf("Input 1st card type and number:  ");
    scanf("%c %d",&t_1,&num1);
    printf("Input 2nd card type and number:  ");
    scanf("%c %d",&t_2,&num2);
    printf("Input 3rd card type and number:  ");
    scanf("%c %d",&t_3,&num3); 
    
      if((t_1==t_2==t_3) && (num1==num2==num3))
      {
        printf("Double Bonanza\n");
      }
    else if((t_1==t_2==t_3) || (num1==num2==num3))
      {
          printf("Bonanza\n");
      }
      else
      {
          printf("No Bonanza\n");
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Puitting all your text in bold defies the purpose of bold

Comment: `x == y == z` does not what you think it does. You want `x == y && y == z` instead.

Comment: for good code style, please further use clamp based grouping: (x == y) && (y == z)

Comment: no idea what "scaping" means - might be some term from card games. the logic hints for something similar to poker. having three identical cards means a "double bonanza", having three times the same value or the same type means a "bonanza" only.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr "good code style" is a matter of opinion there. I consider such extra parentheses superfluous, as I trust myself to know operator precedence (or suffer later if I forget...)

Comment: @underscore_d - well, if you are only coding programs that will make users unhappy by this habit then you will loose money in the long therm. if you are even doing harm to things or people by bad code, then you will probably find out that it might go to court. good code is readable and reliable. the one gives the hand to the other. teaching good code from early newbie days gives them best chances for getting "great" senior coders later. - in this case it would have prevented the original error at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think that an expression like `x == y == z` is true if `x`, `y` and `z` have the same value.

This assumption is wrong though:

It actually means `(x == y) == z` :

- `(x == y)` is either true (that is 1) if `x` is equal to `y` or false (that is 0) otherwise
- Therefore `(x == y) == z` is true (1) either if `x` is equal to `y` and if `z` is equal to true (1) or if `x` if different from `y` and if `z` is equal to 0.

To check if three variables `x`, `y` and `z` are equal you can use this expression: `(x == y) && (y == z)`. The parentheses are not necessary, you can also write `x == y && y == z`, which might be slightly less readable.

Comment: And what will be the solution of taking 3 inputs without having trouble?I can't take three inputs, I can take 2 inputs and on the place of the third input, it prints NO Bonanza.

Comment: @Choyon that's a different problem: just replace `"%c %d"` with `" %c %d"`. `scanf` is a very complicated function and it's not really useful for interactive input, but it's OK for educational purposes

Comment: got it . Thanks a lot